# How jQuery plugin system works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am wondering how jQuery plugin system works.
I've been looking at the development version of jQuery for... hours maybe and I cannot get it. (I guess it's super simple, just I don't see it). 
I know the plugins are just simple extensions to the prototype object, but after two console.logs I am really confused.

```
console.log(jQuery);

function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}
```

And this is what the plugin system (the object prototype) returns:

```
console.log(jQuery.fn);

[jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]
```

How come the `jQuery` is a not instantiated function, but `jQuery.fn` is already an object (instantiated  function).

Comment: `jQuery.fn` is just an object. It is just an alias to `jQuery.prototype`. `jQuery.fn` isn't instantiated (i.e. using the new keyword). `jQuery.fn.init`s prototype is the same as `jQuery.prototype`. That is why when you do `jQuery('selector')` that jQuery object gets all the `jQuery.prototype` methods.

Comment: I understand this, but my question is how come the `jQuery` points to function and `jQuery.prototype`/`jQuery.fn` points to an object when this object must be available after the instantiation of the `jQuery` function

Comment: So you want to know why the jQuery function calls `new jQuery.fn.init`? jQuery's prototype is also applied to the `jQuery.fn.init` method. So that when you call new on it, the jQuery object is accessed, it has all the prototype methods. The reason that plugins use `jQuery.fn` to add their methods is because `jQuery.fn.init` returns an object whose prototype is `jQuery.prototype`. So each jQuery object has the methods that plugins add.

Comment: I will [explain it with code](http://codepen.io/IvanDokov/pen/iEapF), because I think you don't understand what I mean

Comment: http://codepen.io/jeffshaver/pen/sHfdG Does this help? You were overriding Func with window.Func which made no sense.

Comment: The function is wrapped in `(window, function( window ) {})(window)`. That's why there is `window.Func = FuncInit;`

Comment: And when I try to call `MyFunc.now()` from your example it shows error and this is what I want to accomplish jQuery-ish type of methods.

Comment: The reason you got an error was just because I accidentally renamed FuncInit to jQuery for some random reason. Anyway, if you're looking at the jQuery source code (in regards to the `(window, function` comment, that is to handle the AMD portion (i.e. using requirejs). btw, my example is fixed

Comment: I see your example is working, but it's not doing what I wanted: `MyFunc.now()` to call the prototype.now function. I think I've found the key to make it work like this and this is the **makeArray** function in jQuery. The result of a jQuery object is actually an array with all prototype methods as array entries.

Comment: a jQuery object is an object. It isn't an array. It is Array-Like. If you want an instance method you have to create it inside the constuctor. But jQuery doesn't do this often, if at all (I don't believe).